# Unable to use GET Method

Tags: java, apache, http, get

I am trying to write a code which will give me the contents of the page as the response in a string using GET method in java.
Below is the code I am using, its throwing me error that `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol`

If I try inserting http:// in starting of the URL its giving me `Unknown Host Exception.`

```
    String request = ("http://gotoanswer.com/?q=What+is+the+Java+equivalent+for+the+following+in+curl%3F");
    System.out.println(request);
    URL url = null;

    try{
        new URL(request);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(request).openConnection();           
        connection.setDoOutput(true); 
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        connection.connect();

        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        for ( int c = in.read(); c != -1; c = in.read() )
            System.out.print((char)c);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure? For me your code works.

Comment: Same for it is working fine

Comment: Try opening your Terminal (or CMD if you are using windows) and ping that URL.